# Send Push Notification to everyone with Service Worker

Tags: push-notification, service-worker, chrome-gcm

```
curl --header "Authorization: key=blahblahblah" --header Content-Type:"application/json" https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send -d "{\"registration_ids\":[\"blahblahblah\"]}"
```

Currently i am able to send push notification though the command above. In order to send the notification to user, i need to get the registration id from user. What if I want to push notification to everyone (who subscribed to that notification)? And how I get their registration ID?

*Note: what I want is: push a notification to everyone when my something in the website updated.

Link to my project: [Github](http://github.com/limhenry/bulletinbeta)

I learnt push notification + sw from here: [Google Developer](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/push-notificatons-on-the-open-web?hl=en)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you'd need to do is keep track of the registration ids for all of your clients in a backend datastore, and then use all of those registration ids when sending notifications from a backend process. It can't all be done client side in a real-world system—the `curl` trick is there in the sample frontend code as a hack to work around the lack of a backend.

There are a few different backend examples out there that I know about:

- https://github.com/jeffposnick/gh-notifier, which uses Firebase + Node.js.
- https://github.com/gauntface/simple-push-demo-backend, which uses Python App Engine.
- https://github.com/johnmellor/push-api-appengine-demo, which uses Python App Engine.
- https://github.com/googlechrome/ioweb2015, which uses Go App Engine.

Answer (score -1):

You need `registration_ids` (therefore plural) for everyone you want to send Push to.

> An array of registration_ids - these are just the subscriptionId’s
>   you’d have for the users you would like to send a push message to.

Very similar issue is [Google Cloud Messaging send notification to all devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17965922/google-cloud-messaging-send-notification-to-all-devices)